# Salesforce component issue

Tags: layout, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm facing an issue with Salesforce compact layout. One of our users reported that in some WorkOrder records, he can see the Alert component with "Alert details" field (see picture 1). In other records, the "Alert details" field is showed normally (picture 2). I tested same records and I can see the field in both (As I have Read-Only profile).
How can I make this field be displayed for all users in his profile and also in all records of WorkOrder?

Thank you!

Picture 1 (User can see "alert details" field):
[image: User can see "alert details" field]

Picture 2 (User cannot see "alert details" field):
[image: User cannot see "alert details" field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer some days ago.
I had to edit the layout from WorkOrder and find the Alerts related list, so I edited the related list (there is a little icon on upper-left border) to include the field that was missing. It fixed the issue.